# Почему тип char разыменовывается без знака разыменовывания?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, вывод, операторы

```
const char* a="ffggd";
cout <<a<< endl;
```

Почему выводится строка полностью? Вообще как это работает? 'а' же возвращает указатель

P.s И еще такой вопрос,почему в первом случае без const нельзя а во втором можно?

```
const char *f = "аав"; 
char f[4] = "аав";
```

Comment: здесь не тип char, и ничего не разыменовывается... работает потому что вызывается перегрузка оператора << для указателя на const char

Comment: Про перегрузку вам уже ответили. Добавлю про константность. В C++ строковые литералы - это массивы, элементы которых - константы. Вот почему в первом случае указатель `f` должен указывать на константу. Если бы это было не так, то с помощью `f` можно было бы попытаться изменить константный объект. Во втором случае строковый литерал `"аав"` просто выступает инициализатором массива `f`. Каждый символ строкового литерала выступает в качестве инициализатора соответствующего элемента массива`f`. Изменения элементов массива `f` никак не повлияют на литерал, использовавшийся для инициализации массива.

Answer (score 2):

Перегрузка функций.

В С++ функция могут существовать функции с одним и тем же именем, но разными типами аргументов. А поскольку оператор `<<` - это функция

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, type t);
```

то для каждого типа `type` она может быть своя. Для типа `char*` (вернее, `const char *`) она выводит строку, т.е. последовательности символов, на первый из которых указывает этот указатель, а последним - символ перед завершающим нулевым...